# Calculate responses conditional on changed values of another variable

Tags: r

I have dataframe with data from a survey in which respondents were asked the same question multiple times:

```
DF <- data.frame(respondent = factor(c("R1", "R1", "R1", "R2", "R2","R2", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R4", "R4",  "R4", "R5", "R5")), 
                  round = factor(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2)),
                  choice = factor(c("Option 1", "Option 1", "Option 1", "Option 1", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 2", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 2", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 2", "Option 2")))
```

I want to calculate what proportion of respondents chose each option in the first round and how many respondents changed their response between rounds.

I can achieve the first with `tapply(DF$choice, DF$round, summary)`, which tells me how many respondents chose each response in every round. Since I'm only interested in round 1 here, is there a way to get just that without the unnecessary data for the other rounds?

More importantly, how can I obtain the numbers of respondents who changed responses (and from which response to which response)?

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape your data from its current "long" form to a "wide" form. Here is how:

```
library(reshape2)
DF.wide <- reshape(DF, direction='wide', idvar='respondent', timevar='round')
DF.wide$change.1.to.2 <- DF.wide$choice.1 == DF.wide$choice.2
DF.wide$change.2.to.3 <- DF.wide$choice.2 == DF.wide$choice.3
DF.wide$change.1.to.3 <- DF.wide$choice.1 == DF.wide$choice.3
```

The output will be like this:

```
   respondent choice.1 choice.2 choice.3 change.1.to.2 change.2.to.3 change.1.to.3
1          R1 Option 1 Option 1 Option 1          TRUE          TRUE          TRUE
4          R2 Option 1 Option 1 Option 2          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE
7          R3 Option 2 Option 1 Option 2         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE
10         R4 Option 2 Option 1 Option 2         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE
13         R5 Option 2 Option 2     <NA>          TRUE            NA            NA
```

You can then extend on this to determine what was the actual change (like from what to what).